# A polynomial algebra that is free as an $A$-module

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, examples-counterexamples

I'm working through some problems when I stumbled across a question asking about conditions for when the polynomial algebra $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is also a free $A$-module, where $A$ is some $k$-subalgebra of $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$.  However, I'm blanking on nontrivial examples.

1. What are some examples of $A$ for which this occurs?
2. Why are these kinds of algebras important, and where can I look to learn more about this concept?

Comment: If A is the subalgebragenerated by any subset pf the variables, that works.

Comment: @Mariano Thanks.  In this case the rank of $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ as an $A$-module is infinite.  Is this always the case?  Are there other more unexpected examples?

Comment: of course not: the rank of $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ as a module over itself is one!

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space equipped with a faithful linear representation of a finite group $G$, and consider the induced action on the polynomial algebra $k[V]$. The [Chevalley-Shepard-Todd theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevalley%E2%80%93Shephard%E2%80%93Todd_theorem) asserts that the following conditions are equivalent:

- $k[V]$ is a free (finite) $k[V]^G$-module
- $k[V]^G$ is a polynomial algebra
- $G$ is a "pseudoreflection group."

For example, if $k = \mathbb{C}$ then the condition is that $G$ is a [complex reflection group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_reflection_group). These include, but are more general than, the finite [Coxeter groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coxeter_group), and in particular the finite [Weyl groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_group). (The phrasing of the condition here is slightly misleading. Being a pseudoreflection group is a condition not on a group but on a pair of a group $G$ and a faithful linear representation of it.)

The motivating example here is when $V \cong k^n$ and $G \cong S_n$ acting via permutations. Then $k[V]^G$ is the ring of symmetric polynomials in $n$ variables. It is itself a polynomial ring on the [elementary symmetric polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial). The question of what a basis of $k[V]$ looks like as a $k[V]^G$-module is addressed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1004341/polynomials-as-module-over-symmetric-polynomials).

In general, I think the condition that a map $f : A \to B$ of commutative rings makes $B$ a finite free $A$-module should be thought of as roughly meaning that the corresponding map $\text{Spec } B \to \text{Spec } A$ is a "finite (branched) cover." You can write down some nice examples coming from algebraic curves or, if you have a more number-theoretic bent, from rings of integers in algebraic number fields. The inclusions $k[V]^G \to k[V]$ above look geometrically like quotient maps $V \to V/G$.